# Django table - replace ID with two primary keys (or something similar)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table made with Django that looks sorta like this

```
  id         |  user_id    | data
  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
  1119582010 |  1927472901 | foo 
  0318715789 |  2294819294 | bar
  3927284920 |  3281847282 | baz
  1610986385 |  3281847282 | qux
  1948381983 |  2069385930 | foo
  1610986485 |  3103827482 | corge
```

The model looks approx. like this

```
class Data(Model):
   user = ForeignKey(User, delete=CASCADE)
   data = CharField(max_length=32)
```

Two different rows can have the same user_id OR the same data, but no two rows share both the same user_id and data.

Therefore, since each row is already unique, is there any way I can nix the auto-generated `id` column? It takes up a lot of space.

Thank you.

Comment: Please share the model.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with a [**`UniqueConstraint`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/constraints/#django.db.models.UniqueConstraint) for a uniqness constraint (that can span over multiple columns).

This then looks like:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db import models


class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.CharField(max_length=32)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(
                fields=('user', 'data'), name='unique_data_per_user'
            )
        ]
```

> is there any way I can nix the auto-generated id column? It takes up a lot of space.

**No**, this has been requested multiple times, but has been rejected every time. The reason is likely not that much the database; but also how to refer to objects in the URL path and `<select>` widgets, as well as the fact that a lof of Django's "ecosystem" has been built with the assumption that the primary key refers to a *single* unique field.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).